# How to modify the response data of a jQuery AJAX call and return it as the updated jqXHR result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jsGrid` whose `loadData` controller expects the data in an ajax call like:

```
controller: {
  loadData: function() {
    return $.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }, 
  //...definition for others insertItem, updateItem, deleteItem
}
```

The above works just fine.

I now need to massage `data` before passing them along to `jsGrid`. I suppose I have to do it inside the done function. How do I return the modified `data`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return anything from an asynchronous function.

To do what you need you reverse your logic; make the AJAX request to get the data first, then use it to initialise the jsGrid within the callback handler. Something like this:

```
$.getJSON(url).done(function(data) {
  var modifiedData = /* modify your data object/array here... */

  $('#element').jsGrid({
    data: modifiedData
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't know `jsGrid` enough to deviate from the standard way of populating the grid. From the syntax of the working version, it seems that `controller.loadData` expects a function definition and the function is to return the outcome of an ajax call, which according to jQuery documentation is an `jqXHR` object. Is it possible to instantiate a new `jqXHR` object and stuff it with the modified data and return that instead of the ajax call?

Comment: No, that's not possible as the data has not been received when the `return` is hit (which is why asynchronous code has to use callbacks to know when the data is available for use). However it appears you may be using an outdated version of jqGrid as there doesn't appear to be a `loadData` option in the documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: Sorry, it's `jsGrid`, not `jqGrid`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. In either case that library also has a `data` property you can use like above: http://js-grid.com/docs/. You cannot use `loadData` because as I mentioned the request is async and you cannot return the data that the property expects to receive.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you are saying. I have just found an overload of the done (success) function of the form `function(data, status, jqXHR)`. Now I need some `jqXHR` education to stuff the modified results into the third parameter.

Comment: But that won't work. You are returning the jqXHR *before* the request completes. No matter what data you stuff where, the function will have exited and given jsGrid an empty object as the AJAX request wasn't finished at that time.

Comment: It's the callback at done, after the http call completes. I tested and I find that it works! I could simply modify `jqXHR.responseJSON` or `jqXHR.responseText`.  Thanks for leading me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of the success callback with the `jqXHR` parameter:

```
controller: {
  loadData: function() {
    return $.getJSON(url).done(function(data,status,jqXHR) {
      console.log(data)
      //modify data and update it into jqXHR.responseJSON
      console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON)
    });
  }, 
  //...definition for others insertItem, updateItem, deleteItem
}
```